# Should functionalities be in individual classes or in classes they're working on?

Tags: c++, class, methods

My question addresses type of situation, where there's data object (e.g. `Model`), which needs to have operation done on it, which effects in, let's say, making bounding box (out of blue, not what I am doing). Now, should the function `CreateBoundingBox` be inside `Model` class, which will be called on each model individually when time comes or should it have separate class (or just separate function, outside classes) called for example `BoundingBoxFinder`, which would be created only when needed, and would take `Model`s as arguments?

Which is correct or which is better practice?

Or it doesn't matter and it's just a matter of preference and personal definition of organisation?

EDIT: As someone commented - it's basically Factory pattern vs in-class calls. In short, I am asking which is better - to have a factory or factory-like class, or functions inside class (e.g. constructor) to perform some tasks, mostly in significant quantity

Comment: If you need to create an object of certain type you call its constructor. I really do not understand the question. Can you give a concrete example? A class should be responsible for one thing. If it is the responsibility of a `Model` to create bounding boxes then it should have a `CreateBoundingBox` method (but then I would not expect it to be responsible for much other stuff)

Comment: asked differently: why do you need a method `CreateBoundingBox` in the first place? What is your aim? Why you cannot simply create a `BoundingBox` via a call to a constructor and be done with it?

Comment: Responding to second comment - because of all the vertices that are revelant to bounding box are in `Model`, so to not pass it as an argument each time I would call `CreateBoundingBox` in each model I need to. Now, should it be done this way, or as you suggest - by passing `Model` to `BoundingBox` constructor to not to mess with amount of places where objects are created?

Comment: maybe you would like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system

Comment: You're describing a very well known problem without a definitive answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem